# How to put array in an object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to clone an array and return as an object, not an array type.
z

```
 public IntVector clone()
 {

     IntVector cloneVector = new IntVector(3);

     int[] newItems = new int[10];
     for(int i=0 ; i<itemCount_; ++i)
      {
      newItems[i] = items_[i];
      }

     cloneVector = newItems; // is there a way to do something like this??

    return cloneVector;
 }
```

Main method looks like this

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

   IntVector vector = new IntVector(5);

   vector.push(8);
   vector.push(200);
   vector.push(3);
   vector.push(41);

   IntVector cloneVector = vector.clone();
  }
```

*there are two other methods which makes an array:IntVector() and puts value into array:push()

Comment: What's the class `IntVector` look like?

Comment: You should call the `cloneVector.push(newItems[i])`. Show us your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a new constructor for `IntVector` which takes an int array and a count:

```
IntVector(int[] data, int n) {
  items_ = data.clone();
  itemCount_ = n;
}
```

Then you can write clone like this:

```
public IntVector clone() {
  return new IntVector(items_, itemCount_);
}
```

You can make that new constructor `private` if you like, so only `clone` can use it.

Comment: This works, but I can't understand how it is working. What does the constructor doing?

Comment: The constructor makes a new `IntVector` by copying the array and count from the old `IntVector`.